# Python: Scaling numbers column by column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame 'df' in which I'd like to perform some scalings column by column.

- In column 'a', I need the maximum number to be 1, the minimum number to be 0, and all other to be spread accordingly.
- In column 'b', however, I need the **minimum number to be 1**, the **maximum number to be 0**, and all other to be spread accordingly.

Is there a Pandas function to perform these two operations? If not, numpy would certainly do.

```
    a    b
A   14   103
B   90   107
C   90   110
D   96   114
E   91   114
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could subtract by the min, then divide by the max (beware 0/0). Note that after subtracting the min, the new max is the original max - min.

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
    a    b
A  14  103
B  90  107
C  90  110
D  96  114
E  91  114

In [12]: df -= df.min()  # equivalent to df = df - df.min()

In [13]: df /= df.max()  # equivalent to df = df / df.max()

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
          a         b
A  0.000000  0.000000
B  0.926829  0.363636
C  0.926829  0.636364
D  1.000000  1.000000
E  0.939024  1.000000
```

To switch the order of a column (from 1 to 0 rather than 0 to 1):

```
In [15]: df['b'] = 1 - df['b']
```

*An alternative method is to negate the b columns **first** (`df['b'] = -df['b']`).*

Comment: You'd need to take `1-` for `b`, though.

Comment: You'll need to mess with the `b` column to get things flipped. I'd say multiply by -1, apply the sub and div, then multiply by -1 again.

Comment: @TomAugspurger actually I think flipping is more elegant, you only need to do it before! :)

Answer (score 90):

This is how you can do it using `sklearn` and the `preprocessing` module.  Sci-Kit Learn has many pre-processing functions for scaling and centering data.

```
In [0]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14,90,90,96,91],
                           'B':[103,107,110,114,114]}).astype(float)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    A    B
0  14  103
1  90  107
2  90  110
3  96  114
4  91  114

In [3]: scaler = MinMaxScaler()

In [4]: df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)

In [5]: df_scaled
Out[5]:
          A         B
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.926829  0.363636
2  0.926829  0.636364
3  1.000000  1.000000
4  0.939024  1.000000
```

Comment: If not writing a Pipeline, it's simpler to use [`minmax_scale(df)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html) rather than `MinMaxScaler`.

Answer (score 32):

In case you want to scale only one column in the dataframe, you can do the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df['Col1_scaled'] = scaler.fit_transform(df['Col1'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 9):

This is not very elegant but the following works for this two column case:

```
#Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14,90,90,96,91], 'B':[103,107,110,114,114]})

#Apply operates on each row or column with the lambda function
#axis = 0 -> act on columns, axis = 1 act on rows
#x is a variable for the whole row or column
#This line will scale minimum = 0 and maximum = 1 for each column
df2 = df.apply(lambda x:(x.astype(float) - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)), axis = 0)

#Want to now invert the order on column 'B'
#Use apply function again, reverse numbers in column, select column 'B' only and 
#reassign to column 'B' of original dataframe
df2['B'] = df2.apply(lambda x: 1-x, axis = 1)['B']
```

If I find a more elegant way (for example, using the column index: (0 or 1)mod 2 - 1 to select the sign in the apply operation so it can be done with just one apply command, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Acumenus'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832230/acumenus) comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765852/7128154) answer, should be mentioned explicitly as an answer, as it is a one-liner.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14,90,90,96,91], 'B':[103,107,110,114,114]})
>>> minmax_scale(df)
array([[0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.92682927, 0.36363636],
       [0.92682927, 0.63636364],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.93902439, 1.        ]])
```

Answer (score -4):

given a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[14,90,90,96,91], 'B':[103,107,110,114,114]})
```

scale with mean 0 and var 1

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x), axis=0)
```

scale with range between 0 and 1

```
df.apply(lambda x: x / np.max(x), axis=0)
```

Comment: The answered formula for scaling between 0 and 1 doesn't take the min into account. Also, what if max is 0?