# MinMax Scaler in sklearn does not normalize values of column between 0 and 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, sklearn-pandas

I'm working on KNN algorithm in python and tried to normalise my data frames  with the MinMaxScaler to transform the data in a range between 0 to 1.

However when I return the output, I observe some column min / max the output exceeds 1. Am i using it wrongly?

Below is my a snippet of the min/max value returned:
[image]

The code used was :

```
kdd_data_10percent = pandas.read_csv("data/kdd_10pc", header=None, names = col_names)
features = kdd_data_10percent[num_features].astype(float)#num_features contain the specific column labels i wish to extract    
features.apply(lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x))
```

Features contain the dataframe containing the columns (e.g. wrong_fragment, urgent ...).

If i understand correctly, after the execution of the MinMaxScaler, the results returned will ensure each column values will be normalised to the range from 0 -1 only. Am i right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21765852/356729 is exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are right, MinMaxScaler will scale your data from 0 to 1. 0 will be the min of your column and 1 the max.

Apply function will not actually transform your features, it will just return a dataframe with the transformed columns. 
So you need to affect your transformation to your features :

```
features = features.apply(lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x))
```

Comment: this code is not working, if u refer to my code snippet this is exactly the code i used.