# Python: Fast way of MinMax scaling an array

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis

I use the following way to scale an n-dimensional array between 0 and 1:

`x_scaled = (x-np.amin(x))/(np.amax(x)-np.amin(x))`

But it's very slow for large datasets. I have thousands of relatively large arrays which I need to process. Is there a faster method to this in python?

Edit: My arrays are in shape (24,24,24,9). For MinMax scaler in scikit, the input array has to have a certain shape which mine doesn't so I can't use it. In the documentation it says:

```
Parameters: 
X : array-like, shape [n_samples, n_features]
```

Comment: what about using `MinMaxScaler` from sklearn.?

Comment: Theres [`sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html). and also [`sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale)

Comment: Don't compute min twice?

Comment: what is the shape of your data set?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale(x)`? Is there an error message? Wrong answer?

Comment: @MaxU  The shape is (samples,24,24,24,9)

Comment: What is the meaning of the shape of your array?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It is a shape used for Keras convolutional layers, 3d images of 24,24,24 with 9 channels.

Comment: @Wise. Would you be OK with looking at is as a 24*24*24-by-9 array then?

Comment: @Wise. Please clarify your question with some context. The fact that you are unhappy with all the solutions proposed so far means that your question is incomplete. Instead of leaking important details one by one and wasting everyone's time, please indicate where and how you are getting the multiple arrays, what you are trying to do with them, and the issues you have had with the approaches you tried so far.

Comment: did you check [keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.0/layers/normalization/) already?

Comment: @MaxU No I haven't. I use them, but I don't know how it affects the input data?

Comment: @Wise, same here... I didn't start my "Keras journey" yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by MadPhysicist can be optimized to avoid unneeded allocation of temporary data:

```
x -= x.min()
x /= x.ptp()
```

Inplace operators (`+=`, `-=`, etc...) don't eat your memory (so swapping on disk is less likely to occur). Of course, this destroys your initial `x` so it's only OK if you don't need `x` afterwards...

Also, the idea he proposed to concatenate multi data in higher dimension matrices, is a good idea if you have many many channels, but again it should be tested whether this BIG matrix generates disk swapping or not, compared to small matrices processed in sequence.

Comment: @MaxU: You're right for this specific case where full broadcasting is used. But using inplace operators is often a life-saver ;-)

Comment: **This answer is dangerous** because `ptp()` can in theory return 0.

Comment: @A-B-B. Same as manually computing the difference. The question is about how to speed up the code, not catch all the corner cases. That being said, your comment is extremely useful.

Answer (score 4):

It's risky to use [`ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ptp.html), i.e. max - min, as it can in theory be 0, leading to an exception. It's safer to use [`minmax_scale`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.minmax_scale.html) as it doesn't have this issue. First, `pip install scikit-learn`.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

minmax_scale(array)
```

If using an sklearn Pipeline, use [`MinMaxScaler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765852/832230) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest speedup to your code would be not to compute [`x.min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.min.html) twice. That by itself should help by around 30%:

```
mn, mx = x.min(), x.max()
x_scaled = (x - mn) / (mx - mn)
```

You might also be able to get some mileage out of [`x.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ptp.html):

```
mn, ptp = x.min(), x.ptp()
x_scaled = (x - mn) / ptp
```

For that matter, how big is your array that `min` or `max` are actually running slowly?

Comment: Thanks, my problem is that I wanna minmax scale a large number of arrays, so it's not one large array, but numerous arrays which are relatively large.

Comment: @Wise. Then concatenate them and apply the function along a particular axis. Please make your question clear and complete.

Comment: **This answer is dangerous** because `ptp()` can in theory return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured you can still use sklearn's `MinMaxScaler`. You just need to reshape your data to something like `[n_samples, n_features]`, scale it and then reshape it back to the original shape. It doesn't really matter as long as you reshape it correctly. In terms of speed, I don't think it's gonna be really different than doing it with numpy, it just saves you from the hassle of multiplying and dividing.